# Unresolved overloading - trying to make an instance for Int for own class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a class which pre-implements one function (by now) and I want to use it via Instances, I started with Int, which didnt work.
It compiles, but when i try to call the function with fac 3,
I get the following ERROR:

Unresolved overloading
*** Type       : Fibo a => a
*** Expression : fac 3

```
class (Eq a, Ord a, Show a, Num a) => Fibo a where
    fac :: a -> a
    fac n
        | n == 0 = 1
        | otherwise  = n * fac (n-1)

instance Fibo Int where
    fac n = fac n
```

I cannot understand why it isnt working for my class with Int when its working for Show with a new type like:

```
newtype IN_0 = IN_0 Int
instance Show IN_0 where
    show (IN_0 n) = show n
```

At least i think that the misstake is in the instance part, I thought that all i need to do is removing the constructor and replacing the name...
Is something missing, can u tell me the difference of that what i did for show and why it didnt work for my own class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see there are two problems.

Firstly you need to write `fac (3 :: Int)` in order to disambiguate the type of `3`. That will get you rid of the type error.

Secondly you need to get rid of the line `fac n = fac n` in your instance definition. That results in an undefined method. Rather leaving the instance definition empty results in the default instance being used.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, I removed the `fac n  = fac n` line. But fac 3 was just a test, calling the function with the Value 3.
When ever i wrote a function until now I could call it like that...

Comment: Indeed I understand it is a test. Nonetheless my point was you should need write that call as `fac (3::Int)` instead to specify that the literal `3` is of type `Int`, rather than say an `Integer`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I remember what (3::Int) means.